# Removing all rows from matrix A in matrix B

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have in MATLAB a matrix `A` with RGB-values, lets say

```
A = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6;
     7 8 9]
```

and a matrix `B` lets say

```
B = [1 2 3;
     2 2 2]
```

Now I want to remove all rows of `B` from `A`.

The result would be:

```
A* = [4 5 6;
      7 8 9]
```

How can this be done efficiently in MATLAB?

Answer (score 5):

To find which rows of A are present in B:

```
rowmatches = ismember(A,B,'rows')
```

The above gives a binary vector the length of the number of rows in A.  You can then ask for the subset of A rows that were not in B:

```
output = A(~rowmatches,:)
```